# Synchronous Sampling of ADC over SPI on STM32 (STM32G474)

Tags: stm32, adc, spi, dma, synchronous

I have a design incorporating an ADC with an SPI interface that requires:

- SPI Transfers of 32-bits to read the conversion results from the
  previous conversion.
- To be able to sample the ADC at 1 MSps for a    burst of 1024
  samples.
- Phase noise is important, so the slave select signal can not suffer
  from jitter of a clock cycle
- The SPI protocol required by the ADC is CPOL = 1 and CPHA = 1

The ADC uses the falling edge of its slave select signal to close its sample and hold input and begin conversion.  I envision the solution using a timer in the STM32G474 to generate the slave select signal (as a PWM output) and a DMA channel triggered by the timer channel compare used to generate the falling edge of the PWM Output / slave select signal.  If the DMA is configured to write the SPI enable to co-time the transfer with the PWM, the SPI controller forces the clock low when SPI is disabled violating the required AC timing for the ADC.  If the DMA is configured to write to the data register as shown below the DMA only performs a single transfer of 16-bits instead of the desired transfer of 32-bits which requires a burst of two 16-bit DMA transfers.

Ignore Timer 16 in the code below, it is being used to manual trigger Timer 5 which is generating the PWM / slave select signal.

Any guidance on how to resolve the issue given the chosen hardware configuration would be appreciated.

```
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim5;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim16;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_tim5_ch1;

int main(void)
{
  uint16_t i, j, k, done;
  const volatile uint16_t spi2_cr1_start = SPI_CR1_SSM | SPI_CR1_SSI | SPI_CR1_MSTR | SPI_CR1_CPHA | SPI_CR1_CPOL | SPI_CR1_SPE;
  const volatile uint16_t spi2_cr1_stop  = SPI_CR1_SSM | SPI_CR1_SSI | SPI_CR1_MSTR | SPI_CR1_CPHA | SPI_CR1_CPOL;
  uint16_t transmit_data[4] = {0x8102, 0x8304, 0x0506, 0x0781};
  uint16_t receive_data[4]  = {0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000};

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_TIM16_Init();
  MX_TIM5_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();

  MX_NVIC_Init();

  MX_TIM16_Init();
 
  TIM16->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E;
  TIM16->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE | TIM_BDTR_OSSR;

  TIM5->CCR1 = 1;   // Set the delay to turn on time for CH1 / PA0
  TIM5->CCR2 = 40;  // Set the delay to turn off time for CH1 / PA0
  TIM5->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E | TIM_CCER_CC2E;  // Enable all compares 1 & 2 
  TIM5->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UDE | TIM_DMA_CC1; // Enable automatic DMA update, specifically for capture / compare channel 1 - falling edge of TIM5 output used as SPI_SSn
  TIM5->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; // Start the timer counter

  TIM16->CCR1 = 1;

  SPI2->CR2 &= ~(SPI_CR2_FRXTH); // Clear CR2 FRXTH - set FIFO watermark at 16bits
  SPI2->CR1 = spi2_cr1_start;
  HAL_DMA_Start(&hdma_tim5_ch1,  transmit_data, &(SPI2->DR), 2);
 
  SPI2->CR2 &= ~(SPI_CR2_FRXTH); // Clear CR2 FRXTH - set FIFO watermark at 16bits

  TIM16->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN | TIM_CR1_OPM;  // Start TIM16 which will trigger TIM5 which generates SPI_CSn and DMA to trigger transaction

  i = 0;
  while (i < 2) {
    if (SPI2->SR & SPI_FLAG_RXNE) {
      receive_data[i] = (uint16_t) SPI2->DR;
      i++;    
    }
  }

  while (1)
  {
     // main loop

    }

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 32;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Enables the Clock Security System
  */
  HAL_RCC_EnableCSS();
}

/**
  * @brief SPI2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 1 */
  /* SPI2 parameter configuration*/
  hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi2.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi2.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM5 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM5_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM5_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM5_Init 0 */

  TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM5_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM5_Init 1 */
  htim5.Instance = TIM5;
  htim5.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim5.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim5.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim5.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim5.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim5, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_COMBINED_RESETTRIGGER;
  sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_ITR7;
  if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchro(&htim5, &sSlaveConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim5, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_COMBINED_PWM2;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_LOW;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim5, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim5, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM5_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM5_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim5);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM16 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 0 */

  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 1 */
  htim16.Instance = TIM16;
  htim16.Init.Prescaler = 63;
  htim16.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim16.Init.Period = 1000;
  htim16.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim16.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim16.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim16, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_ACTIVE;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 1;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim16, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim16, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim16);

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMAMUX1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn);
  /* DMAMUX_OVR_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMAMUX_OVR_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMAMUX_OVR_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM16 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MOD_MX_TIM16_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 0 */

  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 1 */
  htim16.Instance = TIM16;
  htim16.Init.Prescaler = 63;
  htim16.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim16.Init.Period = 10;
  htim16.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim16.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim16.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim16, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM2;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 1;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim16, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim16, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim16);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way (Free running 1Msps)

1. Set timer (A) to PWM. Use CC1 to generate CS signal.
2. Set CC2 to generate DMA request to transfer 32bit into SPI (there is 32bit FIFO). Select CC2 time to set needed delay after CS assertion.
3. Set indepedent DMA channel for reading SPI recieved data.

Then you need to solve 1024 samples limit. I know about these two ways:

a) Set timer A to gated mode. Use other timer (B) in single shot mode with PWM output used as gate signal for Timer A. When you start timer B, then it will enable Timer A for choosen time (choosen number of Timer A periods).

b) Set timer A to single shot mode triggered by TRGI. Select one of "advanced" timers (1,8...) as Timer B to generate TRGO signal to trigger Timer A. Set repetition counter on Timer B to for example 64 periods. Start timer B. Each period it will generate trigger for Timer A and do one measurment. When 64 periods elapse, then timer B generate IRQ request and your application solve in another 64 beats is the last. If yes, then set one-shot bit in Timer B to be sure that it will stop after that last 64 beats. Thne you should be able control exact number of periods.

If you have troubles with setting SPI to transfer 32bit and you will not be able to solve that. Then you can use ugly solution simly by generating two "PWM"s (and two DMA requests) from Timer A. One for first 16bit, second for another 16bits.

You can also consider to "bend" QSPI to your purposes.

Avoid mixing HAL and bare-metal acces, because then you have poor control about peripheral status. I recomend to use bare-metal or LL API access in this case.